# MS Access: Data not showing update in form (VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-forms

I have a form where the user selects a number from a drop down window.  That number corresponds to some data in another table, which is loaded into a table on the user form.  When I run this code, the updated data does not appear unless I click the toggle button twice...  What is wrong or is missing from my code?  Also, ProductDefault_SchdlNbrs is a subform

```
Dim DltPrvSchdlNbrSQL As String
DltPrvSchdlNbrSQL = "DELETE User_ProductDefaultSchdlNbrs.*FROM User_ProductDefaultSchdlNbrs;"

Dim AppdLevelsSQL As String
AppdLevelsSQL = "INSERT INTO User_ProductDefaultSchdlNbrs ( [Level] )"
AppdLevelsSQL = AppdLevelsSQL + " SELECT Main_Defaults.TextNumbers"
AppdLevelsSQL = AppdLevelsSQL + " FROM User_ProductDefaultsLevel, Main_Defaults"
AppdLevelsSQL = AppdLevelsSQL + " WHERE (((Main_Defaults.Numbers)<=[LevelCount]))"
AppdLevelsSQL = AppdLevelsSQL + " ORDER BY Main_Defaults.Numbers, Main_Defaults.TextNumbers;"



DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Me.LevelCombo.Requery
DoCmd.RunSQL DltPrvSchdlNbrSQL
DoCmd.RunSQL AppdLevelsSQL
Me.ProductDefault_SchdlNbrs.Requery
Me.Requery
Me.Refresh
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: Why use a Toggle button? Why not a Command button? I guess the DELETE is working but bugs me there is no space between the wildcard and FROM. However, don't even need field reference in a DELETE action because the entire record is removed. `DELETE FROM ...`

Comment: I like the look of the toggle...  Does it matter?

Comment: I would say try the Command button and find out.

Comment: Updated the delet SQL statement

Comment: No difference in output between the command button and toggle

Comment: Okay, that is odd. I cannot see anything in procedure causing that. Set breakpoint and step debug. Might want to edit your question to reflect the change to DELETE statement. Won't make a difference but & is preferred character for concatenation.

Comment: Found a work around...  When I added this code to After Update and on click, it worked.